# How can I safely unit test a function without testing every possible 64-bit input value?

Tags: unit-testing

I have a function which checks the parity of a 64-bit word. Sadly the input value really could be anything so I cannot bias my test to cover a known sub-set of values, and I clearly cannot test every single possible 64-bit value...

I considered using random numbers so that each time the test was run, the function gained more coverage however unit tests should be consistent.

Ignoring my specific application, is there a sensible way to ensure a reasonable level of coverage, which is highly likely to expose errors introduced in the future, whilst not taking the best part of a billion years to run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following argumentation assumes that you have written / have access to the source code and do white box testing.

Depending on the level of confidence you need, you might consider proving the algorithm correct, possibly using automated provers.  But, under the assumption that your code is not part of an application which demands this level of confidence, you probably can gain sufficient confidence with a comparably small set of unit-tests.

Lets assume that your algorithm somehow loops over the 64 bits (or, is intended to do so, because you still need to test it).  This means, that the 64 bits are to be handled in a very regular way.  Now, there could be a bug in your code such that, in the body of the loop, instead of using the respective bit from the 64 bit input, always a value of 0 is used by mistake.  This bug would mean that you always get a parity of 0 as result.  This particular bug can be found by any input value that leads to an expected parity of 1.

From this example we can conclude that for every bug that could realistically occur, you need one corresponding test case that can find that bug.  Therefore, if you look at your algorithm and think about which bugs might be present, you may come up with, say, *x* bugs.  Then you will need not more than *x* test cases to find these bugs.  (Some of your test cases will likely find more than one of the bugs.)

This principal consideration has lead to a number of strategies to derive test cases, like equivalence partitioning or boundary testing.  With boundary testing, for example, you would put special focus on the bits 0 and 63, which are at the boundaries of the loop's indices.  This way you catch many of the classical off-by-one errors.

Now, what about the situation that an algorithm changes in the future (as you have asked about errors introduced in the future)?  Instead of looping over the 64 bits, the parity can be calculated with `xor`-ing in various ways.  For example, to improve the speed you might first `xor` the upper 32 bits with the lower 32 bits, then take the result and `xor` the upper 16 bits with the lower 16 bits and so on.

This alternative algorithm will have a different set of possible bugs.  To be *future proof* with your test cases, you may also have to consider such alternative algorithms and the corresponding bugs.  Most likely, however, the test cases for the first algorithm will find a large portion of those bugs as well - so probably the amount of tests will not increase too much.  The analysis, however, becomes more complex.

In practice, I would focus on the currently chosen algorithm and rather take the approach to re-design the test suite in the case that the algorithm is changed fundamentally.

Sorry if this answer is too generic.  But, as should have become clear, a more concrete answer would require more details about the algorithm that you have chosen.

Comment: Thank you, in the end I did do some tests around edge cases much like you suggested, but I also seeded my RNG and ran through 1,000,000 test values just in case.